# Pine Script how to trigger strategy when price goes above level and not after close of bar

Tags: variables, back-testing, pine-script

The script below will trigger the open part of the strategy, the bar after the close. How can I change the variable "Close" so the strategy is tested at the exact point of the crossover of SMA 14 and 28 and not the bar after? Or is that no possible

```
longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the **barmerge.lookahead_on** property, which the default state for PineScript v3 is off.

Generally though this is not a good idea as the crossover may have happened intra-day (or whatever your time period is), then later on that day cross below it again which means once the candle is complete the cross never happens.

If you are concerned about missing the action by entering the trade late, generally a higher resolution time frame can alleviate this